# disabling default regex in search wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, wordpress, search

I am struggling for couple of days with the search engine of wordpress default search.
I am not using any plugin for search.
In my site, there are more than 20,000 posts, and when im looking for a keyword with too many results the mysql is crashing or the http session is timed out.

For example, I searched for ‘q’. and it took between 40 seconds of querying to 10 or even disconnection (depends on how the server is handling at the moment.)
but when I manually queried without the REGEXP part, I successfully got same results in 1-2 seconds.

Can you please guide me where the bold part is implemented so i can remove it from there?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%q%') 
OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%q%') 
/--*- I want to get rid of this line 
OR (wp_posts.post_content REGEXP '\\[table id=(["\']?)(3|6|7|8|9|10|11|13|15)([\]"\' /])'))) 
---*/
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'flagallery', 'discussion') 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
OR wp_posts.post_author = 2882 
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%q%' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REGEXP` you want to remove doesn't appear to be part of a standard "WordPress" install.

To me it looks like a "Table plugin" is adding this, perhaps you are using `TablePress` or something similar?

If it is not obvious which plugin might cause it...

... try disabling your plugins one by one until you get rid of it.

**Edit 1:**
It's the way that TablePress allows the content of the tables to be searched because they are not a part of normal WordPress `post_content`.

Adding the following to your themes `functions.php` would **disable searching of any TablePress content** and improve performance:

```
add_filter( 'tablepress_wp_search_integration', '__return_false' );
```

This might not be the solution for you because you might actually want to search the TablePress content.

Consider highlighting performance issues via their support channels:
http://tablepress.org/support/

Comment: Yes, I have TablePress. I got a huge system to take care of it. what is it TableParse?

Comment: @Meschiany I've added more information on disabling TablePress search to the answers.